# delphi memcached client for linux memcached server working in windows 32 not in linux , encoding issue I think

Tags: linux, delphi, encoding, memcached

I have this TEST console app created in delphi 10.3.2.

I can update a memcached server running on "ubuntu linux" with it from win32 app,
If I compile this console app and run it on linux it will not work.

I think it's an encoding issue.

```
program ProjecttestLinuxMemCach;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, system.json,system.netencoding,system.DateUtils,
  idtcpclient,idGlobal;

var
   tcp : TIdTCPClient;
   s   : String;

begin
  try
    tcp := TIdTCPClient.Create;
    try
      tcp.ConnectTimeout :=    1000;
      tcp.ReadTimeout    :=    3000;
      tcp.Host := '192.168.30.141';  // my local memcached server running on linux.
      tcp.Port := 11211;
      tcp.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
      s:='set q 0 0 1'+sLineBreak+'b'+sLineBreak;
      tcp.Connect;
       tcp.Socket.Write(s);
       repeat
        s:=  tcp.Socket.ReadLn(sLineBreak);
       until (s = 'END')or (  s='' ) or (  s='STORED' );
       writeln(s)
    finally
      tcp.Free;
    end;

     readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I tried to change sLineBreak to #10 for Linux same issue.
When I run on linux I get blank response and value is not set.

Any idea howto fix ?

Thanks

Comment: So have you done any debugging? Have you inspected what is received?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RTL's `sLineBreak` constant is `CRLF` (`#13#10`) on Windows but only `LF` (`#10`) on Linux.

According to the [Memcached protocol spec](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt):

> There are two kinds of data sent in the memcache protocol: text lines
>   and unstructured data.  Text lines are used for commands from clients
>   and responses from servers. Unstructured data is sent when a client
>   wants to store or retrieve data. The server will transmit back
>   unstructured data in exactly the same way it received it, as a byte
>   stream. The server doesn't care about byte order issues in
>   unstructured data and isn't aware of them. There are no limitations on
>   characters that may appear in unstructured data; however, the reader
>   of such data (either a client or a server) will always know, from a
>   preceding text line, the exact length of the data block being
>   transmitted.
>
> **Text lines are always terminated by \r\n**. Unstructured data is *also*
>   terminated by \r\n, even though \r, \n or any other 8-bit characters
>   may also appear inside the data. Therefore, when a client retrieves
>   data from a server, it must use the length of the data block (which it
>   will be provided with) to determine where the data block ends, and not
>   the fact that \r\n follows the end of the data block, even though it
>   does.

Indy's `IOHandler` has a `WriteLn()` method that sends the `IdGlobal.EOL` constant (aka `CRLF`) on all platforms. And the `IOHandler.ReadLn()` handles both `CRLF` and `LF` terminators by default on all platforms if you don't explicitly specify your own terminator.

For a consistent experience on all platforms, I suggest you remove all use of `sLineBreak` from your TCP code and let Indy handle the line breaks for you, eg:

```pascal
program ProjecttestLinuxMemCach;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.JSON, System.NetEncoding, System.DateUtils,
  IdTCPClient, IdGlobal;

var
  tcp : TIdTCPClient;
  s   : String;
begin
  try
    tcp := TIdTCPClient.Create;
    try
      tcp.ConnectTimeout :=    1000;
      tcp.ReadTimeout    :=    3000;
      tcp.Host := '192.168.30.141';  // my local memcached server running on linux.
      tcp.Port := 11211;
      tcp.ReuseSocket := rsTrue;
      tcp.Connect;
      try
        tcp.Socket.WriteLn('set q 0 0 1');
        tcp.Socket.WriteLn('b');
        repeat
          s := tcp.Socket.ReadLn;
        until (s = 'END') or (s = '' {and not tcp.Socket.ReadLnTimedOut}) or (s = 'STORED');
        Writeln(s);
      finally
        tcp.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      tcp.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```